# Win2008 R2 WER ( error reporting ) LocalDumps blocked by what?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windbg, windows-server-2008-r2, crash-dumps, windows-error-reporting

I Just want to recover crash dumps of my own 32bit applications.

I tried the following:

- I followed the steps at MSDN "Collecting User-Mode Dumps":
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- Somewhere on the internet I saw a mention about WER registry keys for
  **32 bit** apps do NOT have to be added under `HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error
  Reporting\LocalDumps\`
- Also that the `..\Windows NT\AeDebug\Auto (REG_SZ)` value must be "0"

Additionally, I have WER error entries in the *'system event viewer'* under
`"Windows Logs\Applications&Services\Microsoft\Windows\WER-Diagnostics\Operational"`
Showing messages *"Possible heap corruption detected (code 3221225477)"*

I don't know if this message relates to my test-app creating a NPE, or if this is WER itself having a problem?

I just can't get it to work :( 
Can anyone give me some clues ?

---

**Update :**
For another fresh 2008R2 x64 machine, i just did the

```
HKLM\Software\... Reporting\LocalDumps\DumpFolder = "c:\crashdumps"
HKLM\Software\... Reporting\LocalDumps\DumpType = 2   (REG_DWORD)
HKLM\Software\... Reporting\LocalDumps\DumpCount = 20 decimal (REG_DWORD)
```

And running the nulpointer-terster worked as expected.

So im thinking there must be a settings in these other machines which prohibit LocalDumps from being used, although the LocalDumps registry-keys are there..

Comment: MS won't fix your programs. What they will do is collect crash reports from your customers that you can sign up to receive.

Comment: That's handy ?! :)
So is localdumps in for the fun of it?

Comment: The first comment on the MSDN article you linked mentions that you should not set the values in the WOW6432Node.  I'd try that.

Comment: Now you mention it, i read that?!
Later when i got desperate i must have forgot the Not bit.

Comment: no, never really found out what was wrong

Answer (score 3):

1. Create key: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps
2. Create REG_DWORD value: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps as 2 (=full dump).
3. Create REG_EXPAND_SZ value: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps as C:\Dumps or where you like. Ensure that this folder actually exists.

Comment: I've done this. I even put it on %LOCALAPPDATA%\Dumps because i didn't know if writing to c:\ is allowed for the running user. But is this actually all you did to het it to work for you ?

Comment: Yes, I have done this on dozens of development and QA machines. Without failure, when a process crashes, there is a nice memory dump waiting there for me. I do not know if the system will resolve %LOCALAPPDATA% for you here. Try a good solid path first. Then create a test program that simply throws an uncaught exception to test it. Also, make sure that the entire path exists. Create the folder if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I read on Msdn that the default goes to that %LOCALAPP.. Path. I also tried the solid paths on different drives. I made a 32bit app which creates a Nulpointer Exception. But its not caught.

Comment: Are your programs 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Both 32-bit and 64-bit, native apps. Note though for .NET applications that this seems to be limited to those targeting version 4 and up.

Comment: This works for .NET 4 as well. The sentence on MSDN is a bit misleading

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already checked most of the common problems. There are 3 more:

### Permissions of the folder to write to

Looking at the permissions of the folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER` it has

- Read & execute
- List folder contents
- Read

Creating a subfolder `LocalDumps` will inherit the permissions.

So you should either modify the permissions of that folder or use a different folder with write permissions.

### Permissions of the Registry key

Windows might not be able to read the Registry settings if the permissions do not allow it. E.g. the following (really silly) permissions will prevent a LocalDump as well:

[image: LocalDumps permissions]

### LocalDumps is disabled

Make sure that there is no DWORD `Disabled` with a value of `1` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps`